# dynamic loop base on object key javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list, I have a search bar for filtering,

```
handleSearch = e => {
    const q = e.target.value
    if(q){
      const filtered = this.state.data.filter(o => {
        return o['name'].includes(q)
      })
      this.setState({
        data: filtered
      })
    }else{
      this.setState({
        data: this.state.source
      })
    }
  }
```

the problem with this method is that I hardcoded o['name'] which is a problem if my list has multiple property.

https://codesandbox.io/s/420lxz97r4

Comment: You can use a variable like `o[prop]` where `prop` is a variable that holds a string (could be the value of an input for example, like: `let prop = someInput.value;`).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir what is ur thought of using `some` suggested by @stdob

Comment: Ah! You want to check if any property of `o` matches `q`? If so then @stdob is exactly what you want. I think I misunderstood the question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.keys and Array.some:

```
return Object.keys(o).some(e => o[e].includes(q))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, forgot there is `some`.I have problem naming things, in map or filter, what is ur recommendation for naming?I can't keep using o, o2, e, v when the nested is deeper.